# Why $\hat{\mathcal{X}} = \mathcal{X}^{**}$ for finite-dimensional Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Denote $\mathcal{X}^*$ as the dual space of $\mathcal{X}$, i.e., the space of all bounded linear functionals on the normed vector space $\mathcal{X}$. For any $x\in\mathcal{X}$, define $\hat{x}: \mathcal{X}^*\to \mathbb{C}$ by $\hat{x}(f) = f(x)$, so then we have $\hat{\mathcal{X}} := \{\hat{x}: x\in \mathcal{X}\} \subset \mathcal{X}^{**}$.

Then in Folland's real analysis, I'm confused about the statement

> If $\mathcal{X}$ is finite-dimensional, then of course $\hat{\mathcal{X}} = \mathcal{X}^{**}$, since these spaces have the same dimension. For infinite-dimensional Banach spaces, it may or may not happen that $\hat{\mathcal{X}} = \mathcal{X}^{**}$.

May I ask why these spaces have the same dimension when $\mathcal{X}$ is finite-dimensional? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why what? Why equal for finite dimensions? It’s because both spaces have the same dimension (a simple linear algebra lemma). Why it is generally false in infinite dimensions? Well there are several counterexamples as you can see by googling.

Answer (score 2):

Ok with your updated question, the answer is that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space then the dual space $V^*$ is also $n$-dimensional, as you can easily verifying by constructing a basis (google dual spaces and dual basis). Applying this twice answers your question. Oh and one more thing I should stress is that in finite-dimensions all linear maps are continuous, so the algebraic dual space equals the topological dual space.